# OpenSource Script To Crop, Resize, Thumbnail, Convert Images

Tags: php, javascript, gdlib

I want to have a section where people after uploading their profile information can draw a square around the part that they want from the picture to be the thumbnail and all that. I'm wondering if there is anything out their with the client side (javascript) and server-side (php) so that I don't have to start from scratch!

Comment: It is very unlikely that you will find anything client side (and very unlikely that you will want to use anything client side!) Searching for a PHP library is your best bet.

Comment: well I just found some Larry K posted that are client side. I think you misunderstood the question. the client side is for the gui to send input to server side to actually do it. It is not even possible client side with Javascript to do exactly what I want to do so I'm not sure what you were even thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ability to zoom the image (resample), then see [kroppr](http://kroppr.rborn.info/). Cost is 29 Euros/subdomain but you do not get source (can't modify).

**Open Source licensed:** see the following. They have less functionality but may meet your needs. Eg user could select area of photo, then you'd shrink it down to the right size on your server.

[Ajax Image Editor](http://www.ajax-image-editor.com/) -- Does include zoom/shrink. But may need work to integrate with your site. GPL license

[YUI 2: ImageCropper](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/imagecropper/) -- BSD license

Comment: thanks alot I will wait a little longer before chosing your answer I still haven't found exactly what I wanted, if I don't I think I'm gonna take some stuff from AIE and put it in YUI ImageCropper and customize it but I was hoping I can find what I want. the way twitter,facebook, and google have it.

Comment: Yeah, I've been keeping an eye out for the exact same reason. The other option is to use one of the commercial SaaS services for this function such as http://snipshot.com/ -- Their integration api looks quite good. Cost appears to be free.

Answer (score 1):

JCrop looks like a good bet
--http://www.webappers.com/2008/09/12/jcrop-poweerful-image-cropping-engine-for-jquery/
---http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

No personal experience with it.